# After call setErrors method in FormControl doesn't show inmediately (Angular Material)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-errorhandler, mat-error

When I call `setErrors` for a textbox `FormControl` instance as shown in the images below, there should be an error message immediately but I don't see it until I remove the entire text.

[image: A text input with a value entered, the input has a required field indicator but does not show an error state]

[image: The same text input with no value entered, an error message is shown and the control is now red]

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
  <mat-label>Registro Venta</mat-label>
  <input type="text"
  placeholder="Buscar..."
  matInput
  (input)="setFilter(input.value)"
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  [formControl]="registroVentaControl"
  (keyup.enter)="addOption()"

  #input required />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)"
      (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event.option)"
      >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of registroVentaList" [value]="option">
          {{option.displayRegistroVentaConsecutivo}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error>El registro de venta no esta activo en SAP</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And here is when `setErrors` is called:

```js
displayFn(data: RegistroVentaDto): string {

  let registroVentaDto = data as RegistroVentaDto;
  let displayRegistroVentaTemp: string;

  if (registroVentaDto.registroVentaConsecutivo) {
    displayRegistroVentaTemp = registroVentaDto.displayRegistroVentaConsecutivo;
  }

  if (!displayRegistroVentaTemp)
    return;

  if (!registroVentaDto.registroVentaId || registroVentaDto.registroVentaId <= 0) {
    displayRegistroVentaTemp = registroVentaDto.registroVentaConsecutivo;
  }
 this.contractService.getStatusSales(registroVentaDto.registroVentaConsecutivo).subscribe(
    res => {
      if (res) {
        this.enableUpdateButton = true;
      }
      else {
        this.notificationService.openError(`Registro de venta '${displayRegistroVentaTemp}' no activo en SAP.`);
        this.registroVentaControl.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });//Here
        this.registroVentaControl.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true });//Here
        this.enableUpdateButton = false;
      }
    });

  return displayRegistroVentaTemp;
}
```

I tried to use this approach but it didn't work:

```js
this.registroVentaControl.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true });
```

How can I validate the input field without having to remove the value?

Comment: Do you mean to have the `emitEvent: true` there? If you remove it does it work?

Comment: Hi @MathewBerg, I tried to remove `emitEvent: true` but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using changeDetectorRef

- Remove updateValueAndValidity method calls
- Mark the control as touched when it has value and untouched when the input is empty
- Set error value to true or false respectively
- Call detectChanges to force Angular to render the error state

```js
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.registroVentaControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if(val.length === 0){
        this.registroVentaControl.markAsUntouched()
        this.registroVentaControl.setErrors({'invalid': false})
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); 
      }
    })
}

this.contractService
  .getStatusSales(registroVentaDto.registroVentaConsecutivo)
  .subscribe((res) => {
    if (res) {
      this.enableUpdateButton = true;
    } else {
      this.notificationService.openError(
        `Registro de venta '${displayRegistroVentaTemp}' no activo en SAP.`
      );
      this.registroVentaControl.markAsTouched();
      this.registroVentaControl.setErrors({ invalid: true });
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.enableUpdateButton = false;
    }
  });
```